# Volume group "encrypted" not found - error message during boot - I did not set up any volume groups

Tags: boot, encryption, lvm

It was working the previous days normally, but suddenly I got this error message during the boot somewhere around the end of `init-premount` or beginning of `local-bottom` or in-between.

```
  Volume group "encrypted" not found
  Cannot process volume group encrypted

Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
```

After the first two lines, the system waits for a minute or so and then continues after issuing a message "Gave up waiting...".

I have custom scripts that mount my encrypted partitions ([source here](https://github.com/vstoykovbg/initrd-LUKS-keychain)). The scripts were working fine for some days. I haven't made any changes to the LVM settings as I don't use LVM at all.

Maybe this bug was introduced after some system package update.

My custom scripts are here:

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/lukskeychain
/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom/lukskeychainclose
```

And the message appears after the `lukskeychain` but before `lukskeychainclose`.

Here how it looks (with more context):

```
We've finished here (/scripts/init-premount/lukskeychain). Continuin...
  Volume group "encrypted" not found
  Cannot process volume group encrypted
cryptsetup: sda6_crypt: set up successfully
cryptsetup: sdd3_crypt: set up successfully
cryptsetup: nvme0n1p3_crypt: set up successfully
cryptsetup: encryptedzfs1: set up successfully cryptsetup: encryptedzfs2: set up successfully
cryptsetup: encryptedzfs3: set up successfully
  Volume group "encrypted" not found
  Cannot process volume group encrypted
```

So the message appears two times, only the second time delay occurs.

Edit: After reboot the message and the delay no longer occur. Maybe some update fixed the issue.
Edit (2): Last reboots it appears again.